# CSS multiple image transitions - need idea

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to create an image transition effect like http://www.molamil.com/frontpage (check on page load how the first section is filled with images), i want to have the exact same effect with css.
here is what i managed to do http://sanketbhatt.com/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#example-1 .box1').transition({ x: '600px', y: '800px' }, 700, 'linear');  
$('#example-1 .box2').transition({ x: '500px', y: '700px' }, 700, 'linear');  
$('#example-1 .box3').transition({ x: '400px', y: '600px' }, 700, 'linear');  
$('#example-1 .box4').transition({ x: '00px', y: '850px' }, 700, 'linear');  
});
```

i am using the basic transition property of css to move the image from top left to bottom right, however i am far from what i see the reference link.
any idea or suggestions on how can i achieve that kind of animation

Answer (score 0):

you could take an element and put a 3d-transform on it so that you get the "3d" look automatically right.

the transform would look something like this :

```
transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(0.1) rotateX(26deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(31deg);
-moz-transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(0.1) rotateX(26deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(31deg);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(0.1) rotateX(26deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(31deg);
-o-transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(0.1) rotateX(26deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(31deg);
-ms-transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(0.1) rotateX(26deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(31deg);
perspective: 1000px;-webkit-perspective: 1000px; perspective-origin: 50% 50%; -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
```

From there on, you could have sub-elements transition from the top straight down into position.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but 3d look is not what i am looking for, i want the transition of images from top left to bottom right, in a smooth manner with some delay in between.